# Training VIT-Adapter on custom dataset

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, semantic-segmentation

I'm training on `mask2former_beit_adapter_large_896_80k_ms` model with a custom dataset and I have two issues that I'm having hard time to figure them out.

1. I tried running `train.py`, but after each epoch, when validation starts, it is slower than training speed which I thought was weird and am not sure what the problem is.
2. To solve the first problem, I have made some changes to configuration file and now during training process, validation is being skipped even though I did not type in `--no-validate` option CLI.

P.S. I'm training on A100 GPU

Here's my code. How can I fix it?

Validation (`test.py`)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNW2u.png)

logfile (I did not type in `--no-validate` option on CLI)

```py
{"env_info": "sys.platform: linux\nPython: 3.8.13 (default, Mar 28 2022, 11:38:47) [GCC 7.5.0]\nCUDA available: True\nGPU 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7: NVIDIA A100-SXM4-80GB\nCUDA_HOME: /usr/local/cuda\nNVCC: Build cuda_11.1.TC455_06.29190527_0\nGCC: gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0\nPyTorch: 1.9.0+cu111\nPyTorch compiling details: PyTorch built with:\n  - GCC 7.3\n  - C++ Version: 201402\n  - Intel(R) Math Kernel Library Version 2020.0.0 Product Build 20191122 for Intel(R) 64 architecture applications\n  - Intel(R) MKL-DNN v2.1.2 (Git Hash 98be7e8afa711dc9b66c8ff3504129cb82013cdb)\n  - OpenMP 201511 (a.k.a. OpenMP 4.5)\n  - NNPACK is enabled\n  - CPU capability usage: AVX2\n  - CUDA Runtime 11.1\n  - NVCC architecture flags: -gencode;arch=compute_37,code=sm_37;-gencode;arch=compute_50,code=sm_50;-gencode;arch=compute_60,code=sm_60;-gencode;arch=compute_70,code=sm_70;-gencode;arch=compute_75,code=sm_75;-gencode;arch=compute_80,code=sm_80;-gencode;arch=compute_86,code=sm_86\n  - CuDNN 8.0.5\n  - Magma 2.5.2\n  - Build settings: BLAS_INFO=mkl, BUILD_TYPE=Release, CUDA_VERSION=11.1, CUDNN_VERSION=8.0.5, CXX_COMPILER=/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/c++, CXX_FLAGS= -Wno-deprecated -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -DUSE_PTHREADPOOL -fopenmp -DNDEBUG -DUSE_KINETO -DUSE_FBGEMM -DUSE_QNNPACK -DUSE_PYTORCH_QNNPACK -DUSE_XNNPACK -DSYMBOLICATE_MOBILE_DEBUG_HANDLE -O2 -fPIC -Wno-narrowing -Wall -Wextra -Werror=return-type -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-type-limits -Wno-array-bounds -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Wno-strict-overflow -Wno-strict-aliasing -Wno-error=deprecated-declarations -Wno-stringop-overflow -Wno-psabi -Wno-error=pedantic -Wno-error=redundant-decls -Wno-error=old-style-cast -fdiagnostics-color=always -faligned-new -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -fno-math-errno -fno-trapping-math -Werror=format -Wno-stringop-overflow, LAPACK_INFO=mkl, PERF_WITH_AVX=1, PERF_WITH_AVX2=1, PERF_WITH_AVX512=1, TORCH_VERSION=1.9.0, USE_CUDA=ON, USE_CUDNN=ON, USE_EXCEPTION_PTR=1, USE_GFLAGS=OFF, USE_GLOG=OFF, USE_MKL=ON, USE_MKLDNN=ON, USE_MPI=OFF, USE_NCCL=ON, USE_NNPACK=ON, USE_OPENMP=ON, \n\nTorchVision: 0.10.0+cu111\nOpenCV: 4.7.0\nMMCV: 1.4.2\nMMCV Compiler: GCC 7.3\nMMCV CUDA Compiler: 11.1\nMMSegmentation: 0.20.2+", "seed": 1493696795, "exp_name": "mask2former_beit_adapter_large_896_80k_kitti_ms.py", "mmseg_version": "0.20.2+", "config": "num_things_classes = 0\nnum_stuff_classes = 20\nnum_classes = 20\nnorm_cfg = dict(type='SyncBN', requires_grad=True)\nmodel = dict(\n    type='EncoderDecoderMask2FormerAug',\n    pretrained='pretrained/beit_large_patch16_224_pt22k_ft22k.pth',\n    backbone=dict(\n        type='BEiTAdapter',\n        patch_size=16,\n        embed_dim=1024,\n        depth=24,\n        num_heads=16,\n        mlp_ratio=4,\n        qkv_bias=True,\n        use_abs_pos_emb=False,\n        use_rel_pos_bias=True,\n        img_size=896,\n        init_values=1e-06,\n        drop_path_rate=0.3,\n        conv_inplane=64,\n        n_points=4,\n        deform_num_heads=16,\n        cffn_ratio=0.25,\n        deform_ratio=0.5,\n        with_cp=True,\n        interaction_indexes=[[0, 5], [6, 11], [12, 17], [18, 23]],\n        pretrained='pretrained/beit_large_patch16_224_pt22k_ft22k.pth'),\n    decode_head=dict(\n        type='Mask2FormerHead',\n        in_channels=[1024, 1024, 1024, 1024],\n        feat_channels=1024,\n        out_channels=1024,\n        in_index=[0, 1, 2, 3],\n        num_things_classes=0,\n        num_stuff_classes=20,\n        num_queries=100,\n        num_transformer_feat_level=3,\n        pixel_decoder=dict(\n            type='MSDeformAttnPixelDecoder',\n            num_outs=3,\n            norm_cfg=dict(type='GN', num_groups=32),\n            act_cfg=dict(type='ReLU'),\n            encoder=dict(\n                type='DetrTransformerEncoder',\n                num_layers=6,\n                transformerlayers=dict(\n                    type='BaseTransformerLayer',\n                    attn_cfgs=dict(\n                        type='MultiScaleDeformableAttention',\n                        embed_dims=1024,\n                        num_heads=32,\n                        num_levels=3,\n                        num_points=4,\n                        im2col_step=64,\n                        dropout=0.0,\n                        batch_first=False,\n                        norm_cfg=None,\n                        init_cfg=None),\n                    ffn_cfgs=dict(\n                        type='FFN',\n                        embed_dims=1024,\n                        feedforward_channels=4096,\n                        num_fcs=2,\n                        ffn_drop=0.0,\n                        act_cfg=dict(type='ReLU', inplace=True),\n                        with_cp=True),\n                    operation_order=('self_attn', 'norm', 'ffn', 'norm')),\n                init_cfg=None),\n            positional_encoding=dict(\n                type='SinePositionalEncoding', num_feats=512, normalize=True),\n            init_cfg=None),\n        enforce_decoder_input_project=False,\n        positional_encoding=dict(\n            type='SinePositionalEncoding', num_feats=512, normalize=True),\n        transformer_decoder=dict(\n            type='DetrTransformerDecoder',\n            return_intermediate=True,\n            num_layers=9,\n            transformerlayers=dict(\n                type='DetrTransformerDecoderLayer',\n                attn_cfgs=dict(\n                    type='MultiheadAttention',\n                    embed_dims=1024,\n                    num_heads=32,\n                    attn_drop=0.0,\n                    proj_drop=0.0,\n                    dropout_layer=None,\n                    batch_first=False),\n                ffn_cfgs=dict(\n                    embed_dims=1024,\n                    feedforward_channels=4096,\n                    num_fcs=2,\n                    act_cfg=dict(type='ReLU', inplace=True),\n                    ffn_drop=0.0,\n                    dropout_layer=None,\n                    add_identity=True,\n                    with_cp=True),\n                feedforward_channels=4096,\n                operation_order=('cross_attn', 'norm', 'self_attn', 'norm',\n                                 'ffn', 'norm')),\n            init_cfg=None),\n        loss_cls=dict(\n            type='CrossEntropyLoss',\n            use_sigmoid=False,\n            loss_weight=2.0,\n            reduction='mean',\n            class_weight=[\n                1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,\n                1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.1\n            ]),\n        loss_mask=dict(\n            type='CrossEntropyLoss',\n            use_sigmoid=True,\n            reduction='mean',\n            loss_weight=5.0),\n        loss_dice=dict(\n            type='DiceLoss',\n            use_sigmoid=True,\n            activate=True,\n            reduction='mean',\n            naive_dice=True,\n            eps=1.0,\n            loss_weight=5.0),\n        train_cfg=dict(\n            num_points=12544,\n            oversample_ratio=3.0,\n            importance_sample_ratio=0.75,\n            assigner=dict(\n                type='MaskHungarianAssigner',\n                cls_cost=dict(type='ClassificationCost', weight=2.0),\n                mask_cost=dict(\n                    type='CrossEntropyLossCost', weight=5.0, use_sigmoid=True),\n                dice_cost=dict(\n                    type='DiceCost', weight=5.0, pred_act=True, eps=1.0)),\n            sampler=dict(type='MaskPseudoSampler')),\n        test_cfg=dict(\n            panoptic_on=False,\n            semantic_on=True,\n            instance_on=False,\n            max_per_image=100,\n            iou_thr=0.8,\n            filter_low_score=True,\n            mode='slide',\n            crop_size=(896, 896),\n            stride=(512, 512))),\n    train_cfg=dict(\n        num_points=12544,\n        oversample_ratio=3.0,\n        importance_sample_ratio=0.75,\n        assigner=dict(\n            type='MaskHungarianAssigner',\n            cls_cost=dict(type='ClassificationCost', weight=2.0),\n            mask_cost=dict(\n                type='CrossEntropyLossCost', weight=5.0, use_sigmoid=True),\n            dice_cost=dict(\n                type='DiceCost', weight=5.0, pred_act=True, eps=1.0)),\n        sampler=dict(type='MaskPseudoSampler')),\n    test_cfg=dict(\n        panoptic_on=False,\n        semantic_on=True,\n        instance_on=False,\n        max_per_image=100,\n        iou_thr=0.8,\n        filter_low_score=True,\n        mode='slide',\n        crop_size=(896, 896),\n        stride=(512, 512)),\n    init_cfg=None)\ndataset_type = 'KITTIDataset'\ndata_root = 'data/kitti/'\nimg_norm_cfg = dict(\n    mean=[123.675, 116.28, 103.53], std=[58.395, 57.12, 57.375], to_rgb=True)\ncrop_size = (896, 896)\ntrain_pipeline = [\n    dict(type='LoadImageFromFile'),\n    dict(type='LoadAnnotations'),\n    dict(type='Resize', img_scale=(3678, 1110), ratio_range=(0.5, 2.0)),\n    dict(type='RandomCrop', crop_size=(896, 896), cat_max_ratio=0.75),\n    dict(type='RandomFlip', prob=0.5),\n    dict(type='PhotoMetricDistortion'),\n    dict(\n        type='Normalize',\n        mean=[123.675, 116.28, 103.53],\n        std=[58.395, 57.12, 57.375],\n        to_rgb=True),\n    dict(type='Pad', size=(896, 896), pad_val=0, seg_pad_val=255),\n    dict(type='ToMask'),\n    dict(type='DefaultFormatBundle'),\n    dict(\n        type='Collect',\n        keys=['img', 'gt_semantic_seg', 'gt_masks', 'gt_labels'])\n]\ntest_pipeline = [\n    dict(type='LoadImageFromFile'),\n    dict(\n        type='MultiScaleFlipAug',\n        img_scale=(3678, 1110),\n        img_ratios=[0.5, 0.75, 1.0, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2.0],\n        flip=True,\n        transforms=[\n            dict(\n                type='SETR_Resize',\n                keep_ratio=True,\n                crop_size=(896, 896),\n                setr_multi_scale=True),\n            dict(type='RandomFlip'),\n            dict(\n                type='Normalize',\n                mean=[123.675, 116.28, 103.53],\n                std=[58.395, 57.12, 57.375],\n                to_rgb=True),\n            dict(type='ImageToTensor', keys=['img']),\n            dict(type='Collect', keys=['img'])\n        ])\n]\ndata = dict(\n    samples_per_gpu=4,\n    workers_per_gpu=4,\n    train=dict(\n        type='KITTIDataset',\n        data_root='data/kitti/',\n        img_dir='img_dir/train',\n        ann_dir='ann_dir/train',\n        pipeline=[\n            dict(type='LoadImageFromFile'),\n            dict(type='LoadAnnotations'),\n            dict(\n                type='Resize', img_scale=(3678, 1110), ratio_range=(0.5, 2.0)),\n            dict(type='RandomCrop', crop_size=(896, 896), cat_max_ratio=0.75),\n            dict(type='RandomFlip', prob=0.5),\n            dict(type='PhotoMetricDistortion'),\n            dict(\n                type='Normalize',\n                mean=[123.675, 116.28, 103.53],\n                std=[58.395, 57.12, 57.375],\n                to_rgb=True),\n            dict(type='Pad', size=(896, 896), pad_val=0, seg_pad_val=255),\n            dict(type='ToMask'),\n            dict(type='DefaultFormatBundle'),\n            dict(\n                type='Collect',\n                keys=['img', 'gt_semantic_seg', 'gt_masks', 'gt_labels'])\n        ],\n        img_suffix='.png',\n        seg_map_suffix='.png'),\n    val=dict(\n        type='KITTIDataset',\n        data_root='data/kitti/',\n        img_dir='img_dir/val',\n        ann_dir='ann_dir/val',\n        pipeline=[\n            dict(type='LoadImageFromFile'),\n            dict(\n                type='MultiScaleFlipAug',\n                img_scale=(3678, 1110),\n                img_ratios=[0.5, 0.75, 1.0, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2.0],\n                flip=True,\n                transforms=[\n                    dict(\n                        type='SETR_Resize',\n                        keep_ratio=True,\n                        crop_size=(896, 896),\n                        setr_multi_scale=True),\n                    dict(type='RandomFlip'),\n                    dict(\n                        type='Normalize',\n                        mean=[123.675, 116.28, 103.53],\n                        std=[58.395, 57.12, 57.375],\n                        to_rgb=True),\n                    dict(type='ImageToTensor', keys=['img']),\n                    dict(type='Collect', keys=['img'])\n                ])\n        ]),\n    test=dict(\n        type='KITTIDataset',\n        data_root='data/kitti/',\n        img_dir='img_dir/val',\n        ann_dir='ann_dir/val',\n        pipeline=[\n            dict(type='LoadImageFromFile'),\n            dict(\n                type='MultiScaleFlipAug',\n                img_scale=(3678, 1110),\n                img_ratios=[0.5, 0.75, 1.0, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2.0],\n                flip=True,\n                transforms=[\n                    dict(\n                        type='SETR_Resize',\n                        keep_ratio=True,\n                        crop_size=(896, 896),\n                        setr_multi_scale=True),\n                    dict(type='RandomFlip'),\n                    dict(\n                        type='Normalize',\n                        mean=[123.675, 116.28, 103.53],\n                        std=[58.395, 57.12, 57.375],\n                        to_rgb=True),\n                    dict(type='ImageToTensor', keys=['img']),\n                    dict(type='Collect', keys=['img'])\n                ])\n        ]))\nlog_config = dict(\n    interval=50,\n    hooks=[\n        dict(type='TextLoggerHook', by_epoch=True),\n        dict(type='TensorboardLoggerHook')\n    ])\ndist_params = dict(backend='nccl')\nlog_level = 'INFO'\nload_from = 'pretrained/beit_large_patch16_224_pt22k_ft22k.pth'\nresume_from = None\nworkflow = [('train', 1)]\ncudnn_benchmark = True\noptimizer = dict(\n    type='AdamW',\n    lr=2e-05,\n    betas=(0.9, 0.999),\n    weight_decay=0.05,\n    constructor='LayerDecayOptimizerConstructor',\n    paramwise_cfg=dict(num_layers=24, layer_decay_rate=0.9))\noptimizer_config = dict()\nlr_config = dict(\n    policy='poly',\n    warmup='linear',\n    warmup_iters=1500,\n    warmup_ratio=1e-06,\n    power=1.0,\n    min_lr=0.0,\n    by_epoch=True)\nrunner = dict(type='EpochBasedRunner', max_epochs=500)\ncheckpoint_config = dict(by_epoch=True, interval=1000, max_keep_ckpts=1)\nevaluation = dict(\n    interval=1000, metric='mIoU', pre_eval=True, save_best='mIoU')\npretrained = 'pretrained/beit_large_patch16_224_pt22k_ft22k.pth'\nwork_dir = './work_dirs/mask2former_beit_adapter_large_896_80k_kitti_ms'\ngpu_ids = range(0, 8)\nauto_resume = False\nseed = 1493696795\n", "CLASSES": ["unlabeled", "car", "bicycle", "motorcycle", "truck", "other-vehicle", "person", "bicyclist", "motorcyclist", "road", "parking", "sidewalk", "other-ground", "building", "fence", "vegetation", "trunk", "terrain", "pole", "traffic-sign"], "PALETTE": [[0, 0, 0], [245, 150, 100], [245, 230, 100], [150, 60, 30], [180, 30, 80], [255, 0, 0], [30, 30, 255], [200, 40, 255], [90, 30, 150], [255, 0, 255], [255, 150, 255], [75, 0, 75], [75, 0, 175], [0, 200, 255], [50, 120, 255], [0, 175, 0], [0, 60, 135], [80, 240, 150], [150, 240, 255], [0, 0, 255]], "hook_msgs": {}}
{"mode": "train", "epoch": 1, "iter": 50, "lr": 0.0, "memory": 49619, "data_time": 0.74881, "decode.loss_cls": 5.78103, "decode.loss_mask": 2.65498, "decode.loss_dice": 4.36656, "decode.d0.loss_cls": 5.93533, "decode.d0.loss_mask": 1.84931, "decode.d0.loss_dice": 4.02757, ...
...
"loss": 121.32677, "time": 5.81762}

...

{**"mode": "train", "epoch": 1,** "iter": 1150, "lr": 0.0, "memory": 49619, "data_time": 0.2138, "decode.loss_cls": 0.5048, "decode.loss_mask": 1.80082, "decode.loss_dice": 3.45238, "decode.d0.loss_cls": 5.58035, "decode.d0.loss_mask": 1.68186, "decode.d0.loss_dice": 3.42048, "decode.d1.loss_cls": 0.58253, "decode.d1.loss_mask": 1.79131, "decode.d1.loss_dice": 3.46671, "decode.d2.loss_cls": 0.51929, "decode.d2.loss_mask": 1.79477, "decode.d2.loss_dice": 3.44692, "decode.d3.loss_cls": 0.48428, "decode.d3.loss_mask": 1.79545, "decode.d3.loss_dice": 3.44692, "decode.d4.loss_cls": 0.48873, "decode.d4.loss_mask": 1.79204, "decode.d4.loss_dice": 3.4456, "decode.d5.loss_cls": 0.48435, "decode.d5.loss_mask": 1.79403, "decode.d5.loss_dice": 3.44245, "decode.d6.loss_cls": 0.48771, "decode.d6.loss_mask": 1.79661, "decode.d6.loss_dice": 3.4401, "decode.d7.loss_cls": 0.48389, "decode.d7.loss_mask": 1.79483, "decode.d7.loss_dice": 3.44661, "decode.d8.loss_cls": 0.49777, "decode.d8.loss_mask": 1.79809, "decode.d8.loss_dice": 3.44472, "loss": 62.40637, "time": 4.38126}
{**"mode": "train", "epoch": 2,** ...
```

File `config.py`

```py
num_things_classes = 0
num_stuff_classes = 20
num_classes = 20
norm_cfg = dict(type='SyncBN', requires_grad=True)
model = dict(
    type='EncoderDecoderMask2FormerAug',
    pretrained='pretrained/beit_large_patch16_224_pt22k_ft22k.pth',
    backbone=dict(
        type='BEiTAdapter',
        patch_size=16,
        embed_dim=1024,
        depth=24,
        num_heads=16,
        mlp_ratio=4,
        qkv_bias=True,
        use_abs_pos_emb=False,
        use_rel_pos_bias=True,
        img_size=896,
        init_values=1e-06,
        drop_path_rate=0.3,
        conv_inplane=64,
        n_points=4,
        deform_num_heads=16,
        cffn_ratio=0.25,
        deform_ratio=0.5,
        with_cp=True,
        interaction_indexes=[[0, 5], [6, 11], [12, 17], [18, 23]]),
    decode_head=dict(
        type='Mask2FormerHead',
        in_channels=[1024, 1024, 1024, 1024],
        feat_channels=1024,
        out_channels=1024,
        in_index=[0, 1, 2, 3],
        num_things_classes=0,
        num_stuff_classes=20,
        num_queries=100,
        num_transformer_feat_level=3,
        pixel_decoder=dict(
            type='MSDeformAttnPixelDecoder',
            num_outs=3,
            norm_cfg=dict(type='GN', num_groups=32),
            act_cfg=dict(type='ReLU'),
            encoder=dict(
                type='DetrTransformerEncoder',
                num_layers=6,
                transformerlayers=dict(
                    type='BaseTransformerLayer',
                    attn_cfgs=dict(
                        type='MultiScaleDeformableAttention',
                        embed_dims=1024,
                        num_heads=32,
                        num_levels=3,
                        num_points=4,
                        im2col_step=64,
                        dropout=0.0,
                        batch_first=False,
                        norm_cfg=None,
                        init_cfg=None),
                    ffn_cfgs=dict(
                        type='FFN',
                        embed_dims=1024,
                        feedforward_channels=4096,
                        num_fcs=2,
                        ffn_drop=0.0,
                        act_cfg=dict(type='ReLU', inplace=True),
                        with_cp=True),
                    operation_order=('self_attn', 'norm', 'ffn', 'norm')),
                init_cfg=None),
            positional_encoding=dict(
                type='SinePositionalEncoding', num_feats=512, normalize=True),
            init_cfg=None),
        enforce_decoder_input_project=False,
        positional_encoding=dict(
            type='SinePositionalEncoding', num_feats=512, normalize=True),
        transformer_decoder=dict(
            type='DetrTransformerDecoder',
            return_intermediate=True,
            num_layers=9,
            transformerlayers=dict(
                type='DetrTransformerDecoderLayer',
                attn_cfgs=dict(
                    type='MultiheadAttention',
                    embed_dims=1024,
                    num_heads=32,
                    attn_drop=0.0,
                    proj_drop=0.0,
                    dropout_layer=None,
                    batch_first=False),
                ffn_cfgs=dict(
                    embed_dims=1024,
                    feedforward_channels=4096,
                    num_fcs=2,
                    act_cfg=dict(type='ReLU', inplace=True),
                    ffn_drop=0.0,
                    dropout_layer=None,
                    add_identity=True,
                    with_cp=True),
                feedforward_channels=4096,
                operation_order=('cross_attn', 'norm', 'self_attn', 'norm',
                                 'ffn', 'norm')),
            init_cfg=None),
        loss_cls=dict(
            type='CrossEntropyLoss',
            use_sigmoid=False,
            loss_weight=2.0,
            reduction='mean',
            class_weight=[
                1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
                1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.1
            ]),
        loss_mask=dict(
            type='CrossEntropyLoss',
            use_sigmoid=True,
            reduction='mean',
            loss_weight=5.0),
        loss_dice=dict(
            type='DiceLoss',
            use_sigmoid=True,
            activate=True,
            reduction='mean',
            naive_dice=True,
            eps=1.0,
            loss_weight=5.0)),
    train_cfg=dict(
        num_points=12544,
        oversample_ratio=3.0,
        importance_sample_ratio=0.75,
        assigner=dict(
            type='MaskHungarianAssigner',
            cls_cost=dict(type='ClassificationCost', weight=2.0),
            mask_cost=dict(
                type='CrossEntropyLossCost', weight=5.0, use_sigmoid=True),
            dice_cost=dict(
                type='DiceCost', weight=5.0, pred_act=True, eps=1.0)),
        sampler=dict(type='MaskPseudoSampler')),
    test_cfg=dict(
        panoptic_on=False,
        semantic_on=True,
        instance_on=False,
        max_per_image=100,
        iou_thr=0.8,
        filter_low_score=True,
        mode='slide',
        crop_size=(896, 896),
        stride=(512, 512)),
    init_cfg=None)
dataset_type = 'KITTIDataset'
data_root = 'data/kitti/'
img_norm_cfg = dict(
    mean=[123.675, 116.28, 103.53], std=[58.395, 57.12, 57.375], to_rgb=True)
crop_size = (896, 896)
train_pipeline = [
    dict(type='LoadImageFromFile'),
    dict(type='LoadAnnotations'),
    dict(type='Resize', img_scale=(3678, 1110), ratio_range=(0.5, 2.0)),
    dict(type='RandomCrop', crop_size=(896, 896), cat_max_ratio=0.75),
    dict(type='RandomFlip', prob=0.5),
    dict(type='PhotoMetricDistortion'),
    dict(
        type='Normalize',
        mean=[123.675, 116.28, 103.53],
        std=[58.395, 57.12, 57.375],
        to_rgb=True),
    dict(type='Pad', size=(896, 896), pad_val=0, seg_pad_val=255),
    dict(type='ToMask'),
    dict(type='DefaultFormatBundle'),
    dict(
        type='Collect',
        keys=['img', 'gt_semantic_seg', 'gt_masks', 'gt_labels'])
]
test_pipeline = [
    dict(type='LoadImageFromFile'),
    dict(
        type='MultiScaleFlipAug',
        img_scale=(3678, 1110),
        img_ratios=[0.5, 0.75, 1.0, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2.0],
        flip=True,
        transforms=[
            dict(
                type='SETR_Resize',
                keep_ratio=True,
                crop_size=(896, 896),
                setr_multi_scale=True),
            dict(type='RandomFlip'),
            dict(
                type='Normalize',
                mean=[123.675, 116.28, 103.53],
                std=[58.395, 57.12, 57.375],
                to_rgb=True),
            dict(type='ImageToTensor', keys=['img']),
            dict(type='Collect', keys=['img'])
        ])
]
data = dict(
    samples_per_gpu=4,
    workers_per_gpu=4,
    train=dict(
        type='KITTIDataset',
        data_root='data/kitti/',
        img_dir='img_dir/train',
        ann_dir='ann_dir/train',
        pipeline=[
            dict(type='LoadImageFromFile'),
            dict(type='LoadAnnotations'),
            dict(
                type='Resize', img_scale=(3678, 1110), ratio_range=(0.5, 2.0)),
            dict(type='RandomCrop', crop_size=(896, 896), cat_max_ratio=0.75),
            dict(type='RandomFlip', prob=0.5),
            dict(type='PhotoMetricDistortion'),
            dict(
                type='Normalize',
                mean=[123.675, 116.28, 103.53],
                std=[58.395, 57.12, 57.375],
                to_rgb=True),
            dict(type='Pad', size=(896, 896), pad_val=0, seg_pad_val=255),
            dict(type='ToMask'),
            dict(type='DefaultFormatBundle'),
            dict(
                type='Collect',
                keys=['img', 'gt_semantic_seg', 'gt_masks', 'gt_labels'])
        ]),
    val=dict(
        type='KITTIDataset',
        data_root='data/kitti/',
        img_dir='img_dir/val',
        ann_dir='ann_dir/val',
        pipeline=[
            dict(type='LoadImageFromFile'),
            dict(
                type='MultiScaleFlipAug',
                img_scale=(3678, 1110),
                img_ratios=[0.5, 0.75, 1.0, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2.0],
                flip=True,
                transforms=[
                    dict(
                        type='SETR_Resize',
                        keep_ratio=True,
                        crop_size=(896, 896),
                        setr_multi_scale=True),
                    dict(type='RandomFlip'),
                    dict(
                        type='Normalize',
                        mean=[123.675, 116.28, 103.53],
                        std=[58.395, 57.12, 57.375],
                        to_rgb=True),
                    dict(type='ImageToTensor', keys=['img']),
                    dict(type='Collect', keys=['img'])
                ])
        ]),
    test=dict(
        type='KITTIDataset',
        data_root='data/kitti/',
        img_dir='img_dir/val',
        ann_dir='ann_dir/val',
        pipeline=[
            dict(type='LoadImageFromFile'),
            dict(
                type='MultiScaleFlipAug',
                img_scale=(3678, 1110),
                img_ratios=[0.5, 0.75, 1.0, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2.0],
                flip=True,
                transforms=[
                    dict(
                        type='SETR_Resize',
                        keep_ratio=True,
                        crop_size=(896, 896),
                        setr_multi_scale=True),
                    dict(type='RandomFlip'),
                    dict(
                        type='Normalize',
                        mean=[123.675, 116.28, 103.53],
                        std=[58.395, 57.12, 57.375],
                        to_rgb=True),
                    dict(type='ImageToTensor', keys=['img']),
                    dict(type='Collect', keys=['img'])
                ])
        ]))
log_config = dict(
    interval=50,
    hooks=[
        dict(type='TextLoggerHook', by_epoch=True),
        dict(type='TensorboardLoggerHook')
    ])
dist_params = dict(backend='nccl')
log_level = 'INFO'
load_from = 'pretrained/beit_large_patch16_224_pt22k_ft22k.pth'
resume_from = None
workflow = [('train', 1)]
cudnn_benchmark = True
optimizer = dict(
    type='AdamW',
    lr=2e-05,
    betas=(0.9, 0.999),
    weight_decay=0.05,
    constructor='LayerDecayOptimizerConstructor',
    paramwise_cfg=dict(num_layers=24, layer_decay_rate=0.9))
optimizer_config = dict()
lr_config = dict(
    policy='poly',
    warmup='linear',
    warmup_iters=1500,
    warmup_ratio=1e-06,
    power=1.0,
    min_lr=0.0,
    by_epoch=True)
runner = dict(type='EpochBasedRunner', max_epochs=500)
checkpoint_config = dict(by_epoch=True, interval=1000, max_keep_ckpts=1)
evaluation = dict(
    interval=1000, metric='mIoU', pre_eval=True, save_best='mIoU')
pretrained = 'pretrained/beit_large_patch16_224_pt22k_ft22k.pth'
work_dir = './work_dirs/mask2former_beit_adapter_large_896_80k_kitti_ms'
gpu_ids = range(0, 8)
auto_resume = False
```

Shell

```bash
python -m torch.distributed.launch --nproc_per_node 8 segmentation/train.py segmentation/configs/kitti/mask2former_beit_adapter_large_896_80k_kitti_ms.py --launch pytorch --load-from pretrained/beit_large_patch16_224_pt22k_ft22k.pth
```

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76320282/edit). Thanks in advance. (But *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today.)